# How Do I Set Bluetooth Headset As Default Recording Device on ASUS VivoTab TF810C?

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, bluetooth

My bluetooth headset does not show up in recording devices on my ASUS VivoTab TF810C. It does show up and work for playback.

I do have both "Show Disabled Devices" and "Show Disconneced Devices" checked.  The configure button, dropdown box and properties buttons are disabled on the recording devices tab.

Restarting the 3 listed bluetooth services and the 1 windows audio service in Computer Management does not change this.

I downloaded the Asus Windows 8.1 drivers package from the Asus support web page. I installed and restarted my computer. No change.

I then removed my headset and re-paired it.  Still exactly the same.

I looked in Device Manager before and after the drivers package install. The bluetooth radio driver says it is from microsoft.

The OS has been updated to windows 8.1

When I first got this computer and did the update to Windows 8.1, I installed all recommended updates and all the available driver updates.  My vivotab would not boot.  I did a factory reset and installed the available driver updates one by one, until I discovered the one keeping me from booting:

Intel - other hardware - Intel(R) Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Generic Participant

When I click more info, I get a page that says "Driver Information: Coming Soon"

With that exception I also had all the driver updates installed using windows update before starting my troubleshooting.

I have classic shell installed and exist on the desktop rather than the Windows 8.1 start page.  Please keep that in mind with any suggestions.

Comment: Unless your headset shows up two times as a playback device, the Handsfree profile is most likely not working, only A2DP. Are you sure your headset is a headset?

Comment: Plantronics Voyager Pro plus works fine w my win 7desktop